# OrientDB: select edge where out=(select ??) does not work

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I have a problem.  I think that this is supposed to work, otherwise someone else would have run into this problem.

The following command works perfectly:

```
// suppose my record id is #10:0

select from MyEdgeType where out=#10:0
```

This works.

```
select from MyNodeType where name="this"
> returns obj with @rid = #10:0
```

---

The following does not work:

```
select from MyEdgeType where out=(select from MyNodeType where name="this")
select from MyEdgeType where out=(select @rid from (select from MyNodeType where name="this")
select from MyEdgeType let $rec = (select fcom MyNodeType...) where out=$rec.rid


... etc.
```

Nothing works.  Nothing. How do I select from edges such that I do not have to know the record id which is incident to the edges I would like to grab ahead of time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're comparing a single field on a resultset (it's like comparing a string to an array), try something like this:

```
select from MyEdgeType where out IN (select from MyNodeType where name="this")
```

Comment: ok, sounds like something simple is going wrong.  

note that `select from MyEdgeType where out=#10:0` works. 

Also, it is not a lightweight edge.

Comment: also, selecting outgoing edges from my node does not seem to have any effect

Comment: I got it to work...going to post an answer, because it works...but I think you probably will know exactly what is going wrong when you see the answer.

Comment: both our answers wound up working, but I accepted yours--worked for a different situation and was very clutch. thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work.

Since my nodes are unique (this is a constraint), I used the unique property to ID them during the filtration, rather than the record id from a subquery:

```
 select from MyEdgeType where out.unique_identifier=...
```

worked.

Comment: My guess about the reason this works is that the unique constraint forces it to only return one result, which prevents trying to compare a string to an array as @dgianotti noted above.